# SQL server. Question about column 'gender' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is are there any gender,age,postcode combinations that have more than one matching individual? If yes, how many such combinations are there?
I want to group by these three columns `gender`, `age`, `postcode` and then using `having`.  but there is an error about column `gender` in field list is ambiguous.  why is that happen?

this is my code

```
SELECT cd.*, sd.* FROM club_data AS cd
INNER JOIN student_data_anon AS sd 
ON ( sd.gender = cd.gender) AND (sd.age = cd.age) AND (sd.postcode=cd.postcode)
group by gender, age, postcode
```

Comment: What exactly does the error look like?

Comment: The error you are getting usually appears when one column name exists in more than one table of your query... so the problem with the `group by gender`

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. if you want to find gender, age, postcode duplicates, don't select any other columns. (Or have them as arguments to set functions.)

Comment: Logically use of a GROUP BY clause without any aggregates is the same as using DISTINCT (without the GROUP BY clause). Perhaps you should address the duplication issue as well. If you select all rows from both tables and each table has a primary key (or unique constraint), then every joined row will be completely unique. Perhaps you really need the common "first in group" logic which is a common topic.

Comment: And if order of rows in your resultset matters (and it usually does), then your query MUST have an ORDER BY clause. The database engine will often return rows in the order of the GROUP BY clause but that is an artifact of the execution plan and not a guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should qualify all table references.

Second, you should avoid returning duplicate column names.

And finally, qualify all column references:

```
SELECT cd.*,
       sd.x, sd.y, sd.z  -- list out all *other* columns in sd
FROM club_data cd INNER JOIN
     student_data_anon sd
     ON sd.gender = cd.gender AND
        sd.age = cd.age AND
        sd.postcode = cd.postcode;
```

You probably don't want a `GROUP BY` either.  It doesn't make sense for your query because you are select all columns from both tables and have no aggregation functions.

Perhaps you want an `ORDER BY`.